# Searching for closed questions returns deleted ones

Tags: bug, status-norepro, search

When I searched for a tag with `closed:1` as a search operator, I found a few questions in the results list that were actually already deleted.

Here's an [example search](https://superuser.com/search?tab=votes&pagesize=50&q=%5Bserver%5D%20closed:1) which returns [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/528087/debian-6-as-server-partitioning). It was deleted on February 9th this year.

Searches should never return deleted posts, especially when you're not asking for `deleted:1`, or when you're not a mod (because guest users get the same results here).

Comment: Reproduced on Stack Overflow with this query: [closed:1 votes:..-3 answers:0](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A1+votes%3A..-3+answers%3A0)

Comment: 10 bucks says this is related to the recent changes with localization :P

Comment: I noticed this a while back on ServerFault: in this query, go down about 8 questions and a whole bunch of them are deleted.  http://serverfault.com/search?page=3&tab=newest&q=closed%3ayes%20answers%3a0%20score%3a0%20migrated%3ano